# Spring Boot logs printing out to Google App Engine one line per log with no metadata

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, logging, gradle, spring-boot

I'm deploying a SpringBoot application to Google Appengine inside of a Docker container, the application works as expected, but the logging is pretty horrible.  For some reason, it's taking every log that should be output and printing them out as individual lines.  Also, the logs seem to be losing some metadata as log levels are printed out but not understood by the Google App Engine log viewer.  Any idea what can be done to help the console understand the logs?

Here are some images of what I'm seeing.  You can see that the logs are printing each line out individually and even logs that were explicitly info, warning, or error don't show up as those level in the google appengine log viewer.

[image: This image shows logs made using the java.util.logging.Logger where I've logged something as info, warning, and sever. We see the logs have their appropriate log level but the appengine console does not]

[image: This image shows the spring boot startup logs where every log has been cut into its own individual line and printed out.]

Here's an excerpt from my gradle build file for the project:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'sonar-runner'
apply plugin: 'appengine'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'

jar {
    baseName = 'consumer'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    compile("org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.10")
    testCompile("org.springfraework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/custom-runtimes#logging) on Managed VMs / Custom Runtimes state that you should write your logs to a location on the VM's file-system: `/var/log/app_engine/custom_logs`. You can then read about the [logs viewer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs_viewer) to determine if you can get it to recognize the log level based on the log line contents.

It may be possible to simply use the standard Java `Logger` if your Dockerfile's image is `gcr.io/google_appengine/java-compat` (the image used when you don't specify a Dockerfile) and simply use the `gcloud preview app deploy` command (the name of this command will change in future) to deploy based on your WAR folder.

In such a case, using [the standard `Logger` class and it's method `log()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#log(java.util.logging.Level,%20java.lang.String)) would possibly be working if you set the log level appropriately, instead of just prefixing the intended level to the log line as can be seen in your output.

I'm unfamiliar with Spring itself and how you would instruct it to do this, as it seems you're not the one responsible for the way it's simply prefixing its intended log-level, but at the very least my answer consists of letting you know this is the key to getting the Developers Console logs to show properly in the event that you are using the java appengine docker image (`gcr.io/google_appengine/java-compat`).